# Kusto, doing anomaly detection using series_decompose_anomalies and run that based on groupie

Tags: group-by, azure-data-explorer, kql, anomaly-detection

I am trying to write an anomaly detection code on Kusto, say checking the rate of selling bad apples compared to all between distributors. I want to make the series and have the bad_apples_per_all_t to get bad_apples_per_all per distributor on daily basis. It is giving me error :

> Semantic error: Invalid summarize aggregation expressions usage:
> summarize must have at least one aggregate function. error comes from
> make-series line

any suggestions?
Here is the sample code:

```
datatable(table_name: string, date: datetime, total_apples: int, total_bad_apples: int)
[
 
    [“distributor1", datetime(2023-06-01), 200, 10],
    ["distributor1", datetime(2023-06-02), 300, 20],
    ["distributor1", datetime(2023-06-03), 400, 30],
    ["distributor1", datetime(2023-06-04), 500, 40],
    ["distributor1", datetime(2023-06-05), 600, 50],
    ["distributor1", datetime(2023-06-06), 700, 60],
    ["distributor2", datetime(2023-06-01), 100, 5],
    ["distributor2", datetime(2023-06-02), 200, 10],
    ["distributor2", datetime(2023-06-03), 150, 8],
    ["distributor2", datetime(2023-06-04), 250, 12],
    ["distributor2", datetime(2023-06-05), 180, 9],
    ["distributor2", datetime(2023-06-06), 220, 11]
]



let start_date=(now()-70d);
let end_date=now();
table_name
|where date between (start_date .. end_date ) 
|summarize all_apples=sum(total_apples), bad_apples=sum(total_5g_drops) by date, distributor1, distributor2
|where all_apples>=100
|project bad_apples_per_all=round(iff(all_apples!=0, todouble(bad_apples)/todouble(all_apples), 0.000000000),10), date, distributor1, distributor2
|make-series bad_apples_per_all_t=bad_apples_per_all on date from start_date to end_date step 1d by distributor1, distributor2
|extend (anomalies, score, baseline) = series_decompose_anomalies(bad_apples_per_all_t, 1.5,-1,'linefit')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you received indicates that there is an issue with the  `summarize`  aggregation function in the  `make-series`  query. The error message specifically states that the  `summarize`  function must have at least one aggregate function.

To fix this error, you need to add an aggregate function to the  `summarize`  function. An aggregate function is a function that takes a set of values and returns a single value. Examples of aggregate functions include  `count()`,  `sum()`,  `avg()`,  `min()`, and  `max()`.

Here is an example of how to use the  `sum()`  aggregate function in the  `summarize`  function:

```
table
|make-series bad_apples_per_all_t=sum(bad_apples_per_all) on date_col from start_date to end_date step 1d by table_name
```

Since the requirement is to get all bad apples per distributor on daily basis, `sum()` aggregation is to be used in the code.

**Sample code:**

```
let table_name1 = datatable(table_name: string, date_col: datetime, total_apples: int, total_bad_apples: int)

[

"distributor1", datetime(2023-06-01), 200, 10,

"distributor1", datetime(2023-06-02), 300, 20,

"distributor1", datetime(2023-06-03), 400, 30,

"distributor1", datetime(2023-06-04), 500, 40,

"distributor1", datetime(2023-06-05), 600, 50,

"distributor1", datetime(2023-06-06), 700, 60,

"distributor2", datetime(2023-06-01), 100, 5,

"distributor2", datetime(2023-06-02), 200, 10,

"distributor2", datetime(2023-06-03), 150, 8,

"distributor2", datetime(2023-06-04), 250, 12,

"distributor2", datetime(2023-06-05), 180, 9,

"distributor2", datetime(2023-06-06), 220, 11,

];

let start_date=(now()-70d);

let end_date=now();

table_name1

|where date_col between (start_date .. end_date )

|summarize all_apples=sum(total_apples), bad_apples=sum(total_bad_apples) by date_col, table_name

|where all_apples>=100

|project bad_apples_per_all=round(iff(all_apples!=0, todouble(bad_apples)/todouble(all_apples), 0.000000000),10), date_col, table_name

|make-series bad_apples_per_all_t=sum(bad_apples_per_all) on date_col from start_date to end_date step 1d by table_name

|extend (anomalies, score, baseline) = series_decompose_anomalies(bad_apples_per_all_t, 1.5,-1,'linefit')
```

[fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/ContosoSales?query=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)

**Reference**: [make-series operator | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator)